# API Manager (1.8.0) busy 'doing nothing'

Tags: performance, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have a clustered WSO2 deployment. The CPU often at 30% (on a c2.large) and despite the CPU usage, the server isn't processing request it just seems to be busy doing nothing.

It seems that the SVN deepsync autocommit feature is the cause of the CPU consumption since if I switch off deepsync or simple set autocommit to false then I don't see the same CPU spiking.

The logs seem to back up this theory as I see:

```
TID: [0] [AM] [2015-02-20 16:30:14,100] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.deployment.synchronizer.subversion.SVNBasedArtifactRepository} -  SVN adding files in /zzish/wso2am/repository/deployment/server {org.wso2.carbon.deployment.synchronizer.subversion.SVNBasedArtifactRepository}
TID: [0] [AM] [2015-02-20 16:30:52,932] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.deployment.synchronizer.subversion.SVNBasedArtifactRepository} -  No changes in the local working copy {org.wso2.carbon.deployment.synchronizer.subversion.SVNBasedArtifactRepository}
TID: [0] [AM] [2015-02-20 16:30:52,932] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.deployment.synchronizer.internal.DeploymentSynchronizer} -  Commit completed at Fri Feb 20 16:30:52 UTC 2015. Status: false {org.wso2.carbon.deployment.synchronizer.internal.DeploymentSynchronizer}
```

and during this time the CPU spike occurs.

As per https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER420/SVN-based+Deployment+Synchronizer I am using svnkit-1.3.9.wso2v1.jar.

I am using an external SVN service (silksvn) in order to avoid having to run my own HA subversion service.

So I have three questions:

1. Is it possible to reduce the frequency of the deepsync service ?
2. How to further debug this performance issue? running this hot smells like a bug.
3. Has anyone managed to get the git deployment sync working ([Link to project on github](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-commons/blob/master/components/deployment-synchronizer/org.wso2.carbon.deployment.synchronizer.git/pom.xml)) with AM 1.8.0 ?

Comment: decided to raise a jira with wso2 : https://wso2.org/jira/browse/APIMANAGER-3345